# Как выбрать макс. значение для каждого типа из массива объектов?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

У меня есть массив объектов. Нужно выбрать для каждого `type` максимальный `number`.

Пока что решаю задачу так:

```
const myArr = [{ type: 'one', number: 1, fiedld: 'aaa' },
               { type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb' },
               { type: 'two', number: 2, field: 'xxx' }, 
               { type: 'two', number: 1, field: 'zz' }, 
               { type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'y' }
]

sortByFields (field1, field2) {
    return ((x, y) => {
        return (x[field1] > y[field1]) - (y[field1] > x[field1]) ||
               (x[field2] > y[field2]) - (y[field2] > x[field2]);
    })
}

myArr.sort(this.sortByFields('type', 'number'));
let newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (myArr[i].type !== myArr[i + 1].type) {
        newArr.push(myArr[i]);
    }
    if (i === myArr.length - 2) {
        newArr.push(myArr[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Такой вариант работает, но как можно сделать это грамотнее?
В результате должен получиться:

```
  const resArr= [
               { type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb' }, 
               { type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'y' }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Я не понял причем тут сортировка, хотя вроде и логично выглядит.

У меня получилось как-то так:

```js
const myArr = [{type: 'one', number: 5 },
               {type: 'one', number: 2},
               {type: 'two', number: 2}, 
               {type: 'two', number: 4}, 
               {type: 'two', number: 3}
];

let result = {};

myArr.forEach((el) => {
    if (typeof result[el.type] == 'undefined' || el.number > result[el.type])
        result[el.type] = el.number;  
});

console.log(result);
```

Бежим через `forEach`.

Если в результирующем объекте нет ключа `el.type`, то заносим ключ и даем в качестве значения `el.number` этого ключа. Если ключ такой имеется, то проверяем на то, больше ли значения в текущей итерации, чем в элементе с данным ключом или нет.

*ES6* style?

```js
const myArr = [{type: 'one', number: 5 },
               {type: 'one', number: 2},
               {type: 'two', number: 2}, 
               {type: 'two', number: 4}, 
               {type: 'two', number: 3}
];


let getMax = (array) => {
    let result = {};
    array.forEach((el) => {   
        if (typeof result[el.type] == 'undefined' || el.number > result[el.type])
            result[el.type] = el.number;  
    });
  
    return result;
};

console.log(getMax(myArr));
```

Если надо в итоге сделать так же, как исходный массив `{type: какой-то тип, max: максималочка}`, то можно что-то еще придумать. типа

```js
const myArr = [{type: 'one', number: 5 },
               {type: 'one', number: 2},
               {type: 'two', number: 2}, 
               {type: 'two', number: 4}, 
               {type: 'two', number: 3}
];

let filtered = {};
myArr.forEach((el) => {
    if (typeof filtered[el.type] == 'undefined' || el.number > filtered[el.type])
        filtered[el.type] = el.number;  
});

let result = [];
for(var i in filtered) {     
    result.push({type: i, max: filtered[i]});
}

console.log(result);
```

---

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, как результат должен быть похожим на исходный массив. И еще, моя оплошность, забил уточнить, что в исходном массиве есть еще одно поле, которое не влияет на фильтрацию, но должно быть в результате. Буду разбираться дальше.

Comment: @Yura `в исходном массиве есть еще одно поле, которое не влияет на фильтрацию, но должно быть в результате` - проблема в том, что если значение этого поля всегда разное, то невозможно сделать результат сгруппировав по `type`, т.к. в таком случае неизвестно какое значение этого неуказанного поля брать. если не группировать - то куда в итоге планировалось записать максимальное значение - мне не ясно....... в итоге нужно было найти все же максимум у каждого ключа или какую-то магическую фильтрацию?

Comment: Из этого массива:
const myArr = [{type: 'one', number: 5, field: 'aaa' },
                        {type: 'one', number: 2, field: 'bb'},
                        {type: 'two', number: 2, field: 'zzz'}, 
                        {type: 'two', number: 4, field: 'x'}, 
                        {type: 'two', number: 3, field: 'yy'}
];
Должен получиться результат
const result= [{type: 'one', number: 5, field: 'aaa' }, 
                        {type: 'two', number: 4, field: 'x'}
];

Comment: @Yura ну просто чуть перепиши в циклах на условие: `if (typeof result[el.type] == 'undefined' || el.number > result[el.type]['max'])
            result[el.type] = {max: el.number, field: el.field};` и всё...делов-то... а дальше этот результат, перегони циклом в формат type,number,field через `for` как показано в последнем примере